# How can I know the settings of a camera without being there?

Tags: video-recording, camera

I am an audiovisual student and I have to record a short sequence of a party.
My teacher asks us for a report with the following camera configurations:

ISO:
Fps:
Shutter:
Codec:
Format:
Contrast range:

My question is how could I know that or how to calculate it.

Comment: Most cameras will include some or all of the things you mention in the image/video metadata. Could it be as simple as just looking at the associated metadata after the fact to note this information? Alternatively, could you just set these things beforehand so that you know ahead of time what the settings will be used?

Comment: Tell them this is like driving by only watching the speedometer... Seriously though, are they asking for settings on a specific camera?

Comment: EXIF data attached to the file might be useful